# Get user rows using their ID from an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySql tables, one called users and the other one posts.

There are two rows in the "users" table, each containing a user ID and a username.
There's also a row in the "posts" table and in one of the cells called "contributors" there are two IDs from the users in the "users table." separated with a comma, so it looks something like this: `0000000000,1111111111` (not the actual IDs, these are just for reference.).

I want to to a "foreach" for all the IDs in the "contributors" cell, basically loop through all of them and for each of them IDs display the corresponding usernames.

I tried many things including this:

```php
function post_contributors()
{
    $contributor_ids = get_post()[8];
    $contributor_array = explode(",", $contributor_ids);
    $contributors = array_values($contributor_array);

    foreach ($contributors as $contributor) :
        $conn = include '../includes/dbh.inc.php';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=$contributor";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            return $row ?? null;
        }

        return null;

        echo '<h3 class="post-contributor-username">' . $result['user_username'] . '</h3>';
    endforeach;
}
```

This doesn't work. I think it's because of the way I get the user ID (I'm left with an improper array).

Hope this all makes sense and someone can help.

Comment: You shouldn't be assigning your `include()` to `$conn`. Remove `$conn = `. That variable will be available just from the include itself.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code.

Comment: @Jordan If the include file ends with `return $connection;` then you can assign the result to a variable.

Comment: It's not a good idea to put comma-separated lists in table cells. If it's always two IDs, you should use two separate columns. If it can be variable-length, you should use another table with each ID in a separate row, with a foreign key to this table.

Comment: What do you mean by an "improper array"? There's no need to call `array_values()`, the array returned by `explode()` will be identical.

Comment: Why doesn't `get_post()` take an argument? How is it supposed to know which post to get?

Comment: Apart from the other comments - your foreach ends with the first `return`. If you wish to have all of the contributors, and display all of them in separate `h3` elements, you should `continue` once you encounter a non-existent contributor, instead of doing `return`. Also, you should store your results in a variable (e.g. `$contributorInfo .= '<h3.......`), and then return it after your `endforeach`.

Comment: `?? null` is not necessary. The `if` condition guarantees that `$row` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your function like this.

```
<?php
function post_contributors($postID)
{
    global $conn;
    $contributor_info = "";

    $contributor_ids = get_post($postID)[8];
    $contributor_array = explode(",", $contributor_ids);
    //$contributors = array_values($contributor_array); <== not needed, explode is enough

    foreach ($contributor_array as $contributor) :
        //$conn = include '../includes/dbh.inc.php'; <== not needed here

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=$contributor";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //return $row ?? null;  <== this would stop your foreach loop
            $contributor_info .= '<h3 class="post-contributor-username">' . $result['user_username'] . '</h3>';
        }

        //return null;  <== this would stop your foreach loop

        //echo '<h3 class="post-contributor-username">' . $result['user_username'] . '</h3>';
    endforeach;

    return $contributor_info; // or echo $contributor_info, if you only want to display it
}
?>
```

A few explanations.

`global $conn` assumes that you have included your `dbh.inc.php` file in such a way that the script in which you call your `post_contributors` function has access / knowledge of it.

`$contributor_info` is there to store what you would normally `echo` out where needed, once you call your function.

The `if / else` doesn't need to return anything, because it would end your loop, and you would only get the info on the first contributor (if they exist in your `contributors` table.

Also, I've added `$postID` as an argument for your function, since you'd need to know that in order to be able to get the contributors.

Comment: Hey @FiddlingAway, There is no need for the $postID since the `get_post()` function gets the post and the `[8]` is the column where the contributor IDs are.

I tried your version of the function and I got this Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in line 162 which is the line where you defined $contributor_info (the <h3></h3> part).
I fixed it by replacing `$result['user_username']` with `$row[4]` but it only shows one user from the array (from what I noticed the last ID in the array) and I need it to show all users from the array. How can I do that?

Comment: That's one way of fixing it. I've edited my answer in the meantime, to show how you could do it by column name - just change `fetch_row()` to `fetch_assoc()`. Regarding the other issue (only one user shown) - are your user ids unique? That is to say, does the table `users` have `user_id` as the `PRIMARY` key, or can multple users share the same id?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! And yes, every user has their own unique ID.

Comment: OK, if that's the case (unique ids), your query should return only one result from the `users` table. If you're getting only one user, check the following: 1) are there multiple contributors, or just one (for the post you're checking)? 2) if there are multiple contributors, add an `else` as the second branch of the `if($row = $result......)` check up, and within it: `var_dump($contributor); echo "<br>$sql<br>";`. The idea behind 2) is to check if you're getting the correct id of the following contributor, and if you are, to get the raw query which you can post inside phpMyAdmin.

Comment: There are 2 different user IDs (both existing in the users table) set.
I did what you said:
`else {`
    `var_dump($contributor);`
    `echo "<br>$sql<br>";`
`}`
But I still only get one user echoed. Perhaps there's something wrong with the function?

Comment: Is the `$sql` from the `else` branch visible when you call your function?

Comment: No, the `$sql` from the `else` is not visible at all. The only visible thing is the one user that's in the `if`.

Comment: OK, that means that the `else` is not triggered. Could you verify that the post you're checking has multiple contributors? You can do that by adding: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($contributor_array); echo '</pre>;' before the `foreach` part of your code. This will tell you if there's more than one contributor for that specific post. If there's more than one, then something else is wrong - be sure to check if you've added  `.=` after `$contributor_info` within the `if` part of your code.

Comment: Oh my god, that was it! I didn't have the dot before the `=`, I just added it and it worked, all users are showing up now! Thank you so much for all the help ^^

Comment: Glad I could help. In case you haven't used `.=` before, it acts the same as in `$someString = $someString. " an addition to this string";`. It's just shorter way of writing it (like `$i += 2;` and `$i = $i + 2;`